# HERE Network Positioning API v2 - NB-IoT position not found

Tags: here-api, positioning, nb-iot

I´m using a SIM Modul attached to a µC, registered in Vodafone Germany LTE Narrowband IoT network (=NB-IoT). I got confimation from Vodafone that their SIM Card is a global one and because of this, it does roaming (=national roeaming) all the time. Because of this GSM location command AT+CLBS does not return a valid location.

As alternative solution I want to use **HERE Network Positioning API v2** but it seems that this API is not able to respone to NB-IoT requests with a valid response.

I´m pretty sure that the assempled HTTP POST request is correct since I test it with expample from [HERE Developer Guide](https://developer.here.com/documentation/positioning-api/dev_guide/topics/example-lte.html) and it gives me a possive respone.

AT Command Response from SIM Module

```
    +CENG: 1,1,3,LTE NB-IOT
    +CENG: 0,"6346,363,-104,-93,-11,3,47922,52334695,262,02,255"
    +CENG: 1,"6346,343,-113,-94,-19,3"
    +CENG: 2,"6346,210,-108,-92,-16,3"
```

POST Request Body

```
    {
      "lte": [
        {
          "mcc": 262,
          "mnc": 02,
          "cid": 52334695,
            "tac": 47922,
          "rsrp": -104, 
            "rsrq": -11,
          "nmr": [
            { "earfcn": 6346, "pci": 343, "rsrp": -113, "rsrq": -19 },
            { "earfcn": 6346, "pci": 210, "rsrp": -108, "rsrq": -16 }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
```

POST Request Response

```
    {
        "title": "Not Found",
        "status": 404,
        "code": "E606404",
        "action": "The values provided in the request cannot produce any content for the response. The location of the WLANs and cells in the request is unknown or the locations of the radio measurements are so widely scattered that the location cannot be determined. Make sure that the network measurements are correct and consistent. Try allowing fallbacks `area` or `any` for cell positioning and `singleWifi` for WLAN positioning.",
        "cause": "Position not found",
        "correlationId": "64b3d10b-0e04-4f16-978a-919f1dd5ba05"
    }
```

**Kindy Reqest your expertise**

- Has some success with Positioning API v2 in NB-IoT?
- More infomation needed? -> Let me know, pls.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately positioning with LTE NB-IoT measurements is not supported at the moment.